# "Продукт питания" уже перестал быть двусмысленностью?

Tags: лексика, недопустимая-метка

Продуктом питания, как мне помнится, являются экскременты...

---

[Большой толковый словарь](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82)

> **ПРОДУКТ**, -а; м. [от лат. productus - произведённый, созданный] **1.** Предмет как результат человеческого труда. Продукты обмена. Готовый п. Обращение продукта в товар. П. труда. // чего или какой.
>   Предмет, вещество и т.п. как результат труда в какой-л. отрасли
>   производства. Продукты сельского хозяйства. Продукты обрабатывающей
>   промышленности. Производить продукты. **2.** обычно мн.: продукты,
>   -ов. Предметы питания, съестные припасы. Молочные, мясные, рыбные продукты. Портить, переводить продукты. Установить твёрдые цены на
>   основные продукты. Свежие, скоропортящиеся, калорийные, замороженные
>   продукты. Забить холодильник продуктами. Отправиться за продуктами.
>   Остаться без продуктов. Продавать излишки продуктов. Удовлетворить
>   население в продуктах по потребности. **3.** Вещество, образующееся
>   химическим или иным путём из другого вещества. Продукты сгорания
>   топлива. Продукты разложения окиси железа. Продукты перегонки нефти.
>   **4.** То, что служит для изготовления чего-л. П. для изготовления бумаги. П. для производства вина. **5.** чего. Порождение, следствие,
>   результат чего-л. Этот вывод - п. долгих размышлений. Язык - п.
>   исторического развития нации. Трудный ребёнок - п. дурного воспитания.

---

Продукт питания - это на выбор пункт 3 или 5.

---

См. [вопросы на Грамоте](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%8B%20%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%20):

> **Вопрос № 261271**     Правда ли, что словосочетание ПРОДУКТЫ ПИТАНИЯ не только не грамотно, но и неприлично? Что нужно правильно говорить
>   только ПРОДУКТЫ, а ПРОДУКТЫ ПИТАНИЯ - это то, что получается на
>   выходе, т. е. экскременты?
>
> **Ответ справочной службы русского языка**
>
> См. ответ № 255416.
>
> ---
>
> **Вопрос № 259391**
>
> Здравствуйте, уважаемые Знатоки русского языка!
>
> Бывая в России и некоторых странах СНГ, встречаю вывески на магазинах:
>   "ПРОДУКТЫ ПИТАНИЯ". Такое  словосочетание лично меня коробит. Продукты
>   машиностроения - машины, продукт фармацевтики - лекарства. Логично,
>   что продукт питания - говно.  Но, извините, ведь магазины торгуют не
>   дерьмом. Допустимо ли в русском языке такое словосочетание? С
>   уважением, Владимир Петрищев Рига, Латвия
>
> **Ответ справочной службы русского языка**
>
> См. ответ № 255416.
>
> ---
>
> **Вопрос № 255416**
>        Здравствуйте!
>
> Ответьте, пожалуйста, как правильно истолковать словосочетание
>   "продукт питания". Недоумение у меня вызывает то, что это
>   словосочетание сплошь и рядом употребляется для обозначения ресурса,
>   необходимого для осуществления процесса "питание". По-моему, "продукт
>   питания" - это результат процесса "питание", то есть нечто,
>   образующееся при питании. Сравните: "продукты сгорания" - нечто,
>   образующееся при сгорании. Такая практика употребления порождает некую
>   двусмысленность. Конечно, к некоторым продовольственным товарам,
>   предлагаемым производителями и продавцами, вполне уместно применять
>   название "продукты питания", но, к счастью, далеко не ко всем.
>
> С уважением, Евгений Колобов.
>
> **Ответ справочной службы русского языка**
>
> Словосочетание *продукты питания*  корректно и зафиксировано в
>   нормативных словарях русского языка в значении 'продукты,
>   предназначенные для питания людей'. Дело в том, что существительное
>   продукт имеет несколько значений, среди них, действительно, есть
>   значения 'предмет как результат человеческого труда || предмет,
>   вещество и т. п. как результат труда в какой-либо отрасли
>   производства' (продукты сельского хозяйства) и 'вещество, образующееся
>   химическим или иным путем из другого вещества' (продукты сгорания). Но
>   есть у слова продукты и значение 'предметы питания, съестные припасы',
>   и именно в этом значении оно употребляется в словосочетании продукты
>   питания.
>
> ---
>
> **Вопрос № 244429**
>
> Здравствуйте! Скажите, правомочно ли часто встречающееся употребление
>   словосочетания "продукты питания"? Ведь, как известно, продукт - это
>   результат какой-либо деятельности. В таком случае, "продукт питания" -
>   это, извините, экскремент!!! Или я не прав?
>
> **Ответ справочной службы русского языка**
>
> Сочетание "продукты питания" не имеет такого значения. Буквальное
>   значение - "продукты, предназначенные ДЛЯ питания".

---

Ответ найден мной случайно - в **[словаре Ушакова (статья ПРОДУКТ)](http://www.classes.ru/all-russian/russian-dictionary-Efremova-term-85798.htm)**:

> ...5. ***только мн., в соединении со словом "питания" и без него.***
>   Съестные припасы. Молочные продукты (молоко, масло, сметана и т.п.).
>   Подвоз продуктов в город. Купить продуктов на дорогу. Продукты
>   питания.

Comment: Мне помнится, что екскременты назывались "продуктом **жизнедеятельности**", а не "продуктом **питания**".

Comment: Ни разу не встречал, чтобы "продуктом питания" называли экскременты. Ни в классической литературе, ни в каких-либо разговорах.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Продукт питания", пожалуй, может быть приравнен к идиоме - устойчивому, закреплённому выражению.  Давайте ещё скажем, что `белый гриб` означает гриб белого цвета.  Уверен, если в Корпусе поискать продукт питания (в разных числах и падежах), это словосочетание всегда или почти всегда будет обозначать одно и то же.

Comment: Вы уверены, что хорошо понимаете значение слова "идиома"? Белый гриб - именно белого цвета.

Comment: @behemotus Белый гриб - не гриб белого цвета, a гриб Boletus edulis.  Шляпка у него скорее коричневая, ножка не белее, чем у других грибов.  Если гриб такого вида почему-то будет серо-буро-малинового цвета, это всё равно белый гриб.  А если покрасить мухомор в белый цвет, он от этого белым грибом не станет.

Comment: Ваши рассуждения не имеют никакого отношения к сути вопроса. Вы только множите свою ошибку.  ***Белый гриб*** назван так именно ***по цвету***. Потому, что у него *мякоть* белого цвета. Причем она не изменят свой цвет даже при сушке, что вообще качество очень редкое, если не уникальное. Но это ладно, мы не биологию и не гастрономию обсуждаем. Посмотрите лучше, что такое "идиома" в любом словаре.

Comment: Я прекрасно знаю, что такое идиома.  И что, что у него мякоть белого цвета? То ли вы не поняли, что я написал, то ли притворяетесь, что не поняли.

Comment: Если знаете, значит умышленно или невольно неверно используете. "Белый гриб"  - не идиома. "Продукт питания" - тоже.

Comment: Можете взять любое определение. Вот такое например: "Идиома - это свойственное только данному языку устойчивое словосочетание, ***значение которого не определяется значением входящих в него слов взятых по отдельности***. Белый гриб - это именно белый и именно гриб. "Продукт питания" - это именно продукт и именно питания, во всяком случае имеет прямое к питанию отношение.  Добавить тут нечего.

Comment: Правильное определение.  "Белый гриб - это именно белый и именно гриб." - неправильно.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для дискуссий. Простите.

Comment: Хе-хе, дискуссию начали вы.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39640/discussion-between-behemothus-and-user31264).

Answer (score 0):

Продукты питания — болезни, в основном (это на тему выбора 3 или 5). Предложу взамен расхожего «нормальный» вариант: пищевые продукты.

Answer (score 0):

"Продукт питания" - выражение устоявшееся, но, конечно, никакая не идиома. Можно спорить, насколько правильное, но  это уже другое. Продукт он потому, что его произвели специально или по крайней мере собрали, а питание - это назначение.

Родительный падеж у "питания" здесь не означает продукт, полученный в результате питания (это вообще не такая уж и частая функция родительного, не совсем понятно, почему она здесь выпячивается некоторыми), это всего лишь притяжательность или отнесение к определенной категории, области. Т. е. "продукт питания" надо понимать как "продукт для питания".

Повторюсь, я не настаиваю на абсолютной правильности этого образования, но по крайней мере его вполне можно объяснить, если не замыкаться на версии об экскрементах.

Comment: "Продукт питания" и "продукт для питания" - это все-таки грамматически разные вещи, вряд ли семантика может быть общей до тождественности.

Comment: @Morkovkin Дело давнее, но не помню, чтобы я говорил о какой-то "тождественности". Меня смутила подмена "результат" на "продукт." в вопросе. Вот уж где ни о какой тождественности речи не может быть в принципе. Извините, только сейчас обнаружил, что не ответил сразу.